# How can I set PHPMD rule properties?

Tags: php, phpmd

I'm new to using PHP Mess Detector (PHPMD) and want to teak some of the parameters. For example, the naming rules are giving me output like this:

```
"Avoid variables with short names like $id. Configured minimum length is 3."
```

Can I change the "configured minimum length" without copying and altering the XML ruleset file?

The message suggests to me that the user of this ruleset can configure these boundaries, and in [the Naming Rules docs](http://phpmd.org/rules/naming.html) are "properties" summaries for each method with a "default value".

Can I specify properties on the command line, or is there a general config file somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you will have to copy and alter the ruleset file. PHPMD does not support clanging properties on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. It was easy enough to copy, tweak and use the new ruleset.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using configuration file you can override properties like this

`phpmd /path/to/source text codesize,/my/rules.xml`

```
<!--/my/rules.xml-->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="Some ruleset"
         xmlns="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset/1.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset/1.0.0
                     http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset_xml_schema.xsd"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="
                     http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset_xml_schema.xsd">

<!--The part you are interested in-->
    <rule ref="rulesets/naming.xml/ShortVariable">
        <properties>
            <property name="minimum" description="Minimum length for a variable, property or parameter name" value="2"/>
        </properties>
</rule>
```